# emptying an array upon closing a dialog with Javascript and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I'm using AngularJS.  The following code sits in a controller.  I'm trying to fill $scope.highlighted with Objects whose highlight property is set to true.  I need $scope.highlighted to be emptied when the dialog is closed.  For some reason, the $scope.highlighted in my closeDialog() function is not the same array I propagate in getHighlighted().  I can't tell if this is a AngularJS scope problem, a JavaScript reference issue, or something else?

```
            $scope.highlighted = [];

            $scope.closeDialog = function () {
                console.log("closeDialog");
                // Hide the dialog
                $('#shared-list .modal').modal('hide');
                // Clean up data for next shared list
                console.log($scope.highlighted);
                while ($scope.highlighted.length > 0) {
                    console.log("pop");
                    $scope.highlighted.pop();
                }
                console.log($scope.highlighted);
            };

            $scope.getHighlighted = function (root) {
                var x, y;
                for (x in root.CurrentItems) {
                    console.log(root.CurrentItems[x].ItemLabel + ": " + root.CurrentItems[x].highlight);
                    if (root.CurrentItems[x].highlight == true) {
                        console.log("push");
                        $scope.highlighted.push(root.CurrentItems[x]);
                    }
                }
                for (y in root.Folders) {
                    console.log(root.Folders[y].FolderLabel + ": " + root.Folders[y].highlight);
                    if (root.Folders[y].highlight == true) {
                        console.log("push");
                        $scope.highlighted.push(root.Folders[y]);
                    }
                    $scope.getHighlighted(root.Folders[y]);
                }
            };

            $scope.showCreateSharedList = function () {
                console.log("showShared");
                console.log($scope.highlighted);
                $scope.getHighlighted($scope.favorites);
                console.log($scope.highlighted);
                if ($scope.highlighted.length == 0) {
                    alert("Please select one or more items and/or folders to share.");
                }
                else {
                    $("#shared-list .modal").modal();
                }
            };
```

Comment: Why do you say it isn't the same array?  What does the console show after `console.log($scope.highlighted);` in the `closeDialog` function?  Can you make a plunker?

Comment: @Jerrad It shows an empty array

Comment: Hard to diagnose without seeing more code.